# Enum False Error. "cannot be referred to before it is declared"

Tags: vb.net, enums, compiler-errors, visual-studio-2019

I am using VB.NET in VS2019 and I had an error with an "Enum" that had me going in circles for quite a while. I have included a screen grab of the minimum reproducible code as I think it shows the issue more clearly. In the code you can see I have two errors so I went to the top error in the list (local variable cannot be referred to) and inspected the line of code. The line looked correct and my Enum declaration showed no errors but hovering over the error line gave me the error message and when I right clicked the Enum in the line and selected "go to destination" it took me nowhere. It was as if the Enum was not declared. After some time head scratching I eventually gave up with this line of code thinking I must be missing something and I went to the second error. The missing array variable name in the second error was obvious and fixed easily but I also noticed that fixing this totally unconnected line also fixed the first error. It's as if the second error caused the Enum declaration to become invalid. So my question: Is this normal for an Enum to become non-existent affecting all previous usage if it is used incorrectly later in the same subroutine? I'm sure this is not the first time I have made a typing error like this but I don't remember ever being misdirected in this way. Thanks.

[image: Code Screen Grab]

The code below shows the code with and without the error.

```
Public Enum MyEnum
    FirstValue = 0
    SecondValue
End Enum
Public Sub TestSub() 'Shows Enum error
    Dim arr(1, 1) As Integer
    'The next line shows an Enum cannot be referenced error.
    Dim x As Double = CDbl(arr(1, MyEnum.FirstValue))
    'Just some abitrary code
    Dim doSomething As Double = 0
    Dim doSomethingElse As Double = 0
    Dim doACalculation As Double = doSomething * doSomethingElse
    'The next line was inadvertently edited wrong.
    Dim y As Double = CDbl(1, MyEnum.SecondValue)
End Sub

Public Sub TestSub2() 'No errors
    Dim arr(1, 1) As Integer
    'The next line was not altered in any way but now shows no error.
    Dim x As Double = CDbl(arr(1, MyEnum.FirstValue))
    'Just some abitrary code
    Dim doSomething As Double = 0
    Dim doSomethingElse As Double = 0
    Dim doACalculation As Double = doSomething * doSomethingElse
    'When this line was corrected the previous error also went away.
    Dim y As Double = CDbl(arr(1, MyEnum.SecondValue))
End Sub
```

Comment: Just seen your edited reply Jimi. The error in the second line didn't leap out at me as being a possible cause of previous errors but yes with your explanation it makes perfect sense now. Thanks for that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To formalise what Jimi put in his comment, the compiler is making it's best guess at what you're trying to achieve in this line:

```vb
Dim y As Double = CDbl(1, MyEnum.SecondValue)
```

and what it comes up with is this:

```vb
Dim y As Double = CDbl(1), MyEnum
```

It thinks that you missed a closing parenthesis before the comma, which the second error message is telling you, and that you then butchered the declaration of a `MyEnum` variable. As suggested, that variable takes precedence over a type with the same name so, in that method, the compiler thinks that the first line in error is trying to use that variable before it has been declared rather than trying to use the `Enum`.

Comment: Thanks jmcilhinney Makes perfect sense. "Oh what a tangled web we weave!"

Comment: @Rodent, if this answer resolves your issue then you should accept it. I believe that you had done so but then undid it. Part of the point of accepting an answer is to show other users that you no longer need help without their having to open the question and read all the comments. If you're concerned that the original idea for the solution was from Jimi then don't be. I have prompted Jimi to write answers rather than comments many times but he basically refuses to do so. If he cared about the reputation points then he'd write his own answers.

Comment: jmcilhinney. Sorry but I didn't realise I had undone anything. I think it's ok now. Thanks for your help and advice.